# Add price suffix ro Woocommerce shop loop based on country

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to display a price suffix in the Woocommerce shop loop but NOT for three specific countries. So for example, if a customer from Switzerland or Norway is visiting the site, the suffix should NOT be displayed. But for all other countries it should be. I have only tried using css with the pseudoelement after, but this results in the suffix always being displayed.

Comment: How do you identify from which country a user is? If you have php function to do that, you can overwrite the template for price.php in single-product/price.php and instead of getting out $product->get_price_html(); for these specific countries to just get out $product->get_price(); This doesn't have any html (suffix etc) and you can modify it whatever way you like.

Comment: The country is selected when the user uses the shipping calculator on the cart page. The default which is set before is the shop base.

Answer (score 1):

You Can try one the following approaches. The approach is the same, find out the country from the shipping_country function and modify your pricing accordingly. It might happen that get_shipping_country returns a string. Then you'll need to modify the if function.

1: Modify the template /loop/price.php as well as /single-product/price.php in your childtheme or main theme

```
global $woocommerce;
$countries = array('NR', 'CH');
   
if ( in_array( $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_country(), $countries ) ) :
   
// not sure about the country codes. You should double check that.
// just call your basic price function. Which you can customize yourself or use of the other pricing functions.
echo $product->get_price();
: else ?>
<p class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_price_class', 'price' ) ); ?>"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>
<?php endif;
```

2: Add a filter for the price_html in your functions.php of a plugin or childtheme

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'adjust_price_html', 100, 2 );




// callback function to adjust price based on country
function adjust_price_html( $price, $product ){
    global $woocommerce_loop;

    $wLoop = true;

// for related loop
if ( is_product() && $woocommerce_loop['name'] == 'related' ) :
    display_price_html_based_on_country($price);
elseif (is_shop() || is_product_category()) :

    display_price_html_based_on_country($price);
else :

    // this is single_product
    if(is_product()){
        return $price;
    } else {

        // here you can modify shortcode output

        display_price_html_based_on_country($price);
    }

    endif;
    

}

function display_price_html_based_on_country($price){
    global $woocommerce;
    $countries = array('NR', 'CH');

    if ( in_array( $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_country(), $countries ) ) :


    // here you can play with the price you get
    // or call other data from the $product object. For example 
    $product->get_price();
    return $price;
    endif;

}
```

Comment: I don't have that much knowledge in PHP. My perferd methid would be to use the filter, but I only need the price on the archive pages have the suffix, not the single product price.

Comment: The problem is that is_shop does not include related products, up-sells or anywhere the product shortcode is used. I need the suffix everywhere the products are displayed in the loop (so in the grid), but NOT at the single-poduct pice.

Comment: AH ok. That's also no problem. Will adjust the conditional logic. Maybe you should mention these details in your description next time.